# How to let user login on Mezzanine tutorial website?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I just installed Mezzanine on my linux server. Following the tutorial, with the command set

```
mezzanine-project project_name
cd project_name
python manage.py createdb --noinput
python manage.py runserver
```

Now I have the first simple site working now.

In the setting, there is a check box about

"Accounts required for commenting: If True, users must log in to comment"

But I can't see any log in function provided on the tutorial website.

Should we just handcraft the create account/ log in function? Or is there a better way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the mezzanine.accounts app which has provides all the login functionality.

This is entirely covered in the documentation:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html

Comment: I enabled this function, but user don't have it's personal web page, that's my question :|

Comment: Did you read the section on profiles? It's right there in the docs page I linked to. Once you have profile configured, users will have their own profile pages.

Comment: I just checked that, but I can't find the model.py in my Mezzanine project folder. When I use `mezzanine-project` command to create a folder for my site, there is no model.py in it which confuse me a lot (Cause that seems should be necessary for Django project?) Still, thanks for your help though.

Comment: I created a new app following the instruction at the document, but then when I click on the name shown in my site, the error pops: "DoesNotExist at /account/update/
MyProfile matching query does not exist."